# Help using substitution to evaluate $\int_3^6(-x^2+2x+3)^2\,dx$

Tags: calculus

Can you point out where I go wrong in integrating $$\int_3^6(-x^2+2x+3)^2\,dx$$

I run into trouble trying to substitute in $u=-x^2+2x+3$ and then get

$$\frac{du}{dx}=-2x+2$$
$$\frac{du}{-2x+2}=dx$$

$$\int_3^6u^2\,\frac{du}{-2x+2}$$

$$\left[\frac13 (-x^2+2x+3)^3\,\frac{1}{-2x+2}\right]_3^6$$

I get the wrong answer doing it this way so where's the error that I'm introducing? I suspect there's a problem with integrating with respect to $du$ while there is an $x$ in the denominator. If that is the problem how do I correct it?

When I integrate after expanding out $(-x^2+2x+3)^2$ I can get the right answer but it takes me quite a bit longer to calculate.

Comment: You are correct that that is where your error comes from. You want to integrate with respect to $u$, but with $x$ still present in the integrand, the integration will not behave nicely (since $u$ and $x$ are dependant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $-x^2+2x+3=4-(x-1)^2$  one option can be substituting $x-1$ with $y$ which will immediately  eliminate cubic & one degree terms

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $(-x^2+2x+3)^2=[-x^2+3x-x+3]^2=[-x(x-3)-1\times(x-3)]^2=(x-3)^2((x+1)^2$

Now put $z=x-3\Rightarrow dx=dz$ and $x+1=z+4$